# How to pass output of separate console window to Visual Studio output window?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, console, visual-studio-debugging

I'm writing an application in C# that uses an OpenGL binding ([OpenGL.NET](https://github.com/luca-piccioni/OpenGL.Net)) and a GLFW library binding.
When running the application, it shows the black console window and uses this for displaying all console output (the `Console.WriteLine` output appears here).

Nothing shows up in the Visual Studio output window, as it normally would.
I'm used to view the Visual Studio output window and never used some software that creates its own console / command line for whatever reason.
Although it is not a big problem, it's irritating that (when debugging) all output in that separate console is lost when I close my application.

I'm sure this situation has something to do with the software architecture/properties of the included third party software I mentioned.

**My question is:** is it possible to somehow pass/copy the console output like `Console.WriteLine` that shows up in the separate console, to the output window of Visual Studio? And if possible, how to do it?
If possible I prefer not to use a different method or functionality for outputting things to the console. So avoiding to change every line where I use `Console.WriteLine`.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: I think you can use `Debug.WriteLine()` with `System.Diagnostics` namespace to quickly print a message to the output window of the IDE.

Comment: Please let us know if it helps or not.

Comment: Your answer has helped me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to pass output of separate console window to Visual Studio output
> window?

You can use `Debug.WriteLine()` with using namespace `System.Diagnostics`, it will output the info on the output window.

There is no other easy function copying the info from console window into output window directly. Only manually use `Debug.Writeline()` to add any information you want.

**Note**: You should use **Start Debugging** under **Debug** menu rather than **Start without Debugging** and then you will see them on the **output window**.

**2)** **Besides**, if you use **Release** configuration or use other configurations that are not **Debug** to run your project, `Debug.writeline()` will not work.

**Instead**, you should use

```
 Trace.WriteLine();
```

**Also**, it can be used in the Debug configuration.

**In other words**, it is better to use it.